# My ng-repeat is working only alphabetically |angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to implement an app where there can be infinite number of products in an object 
    The JSON

```
 $scope.tableContent = [
        {
            id: 1,
            sks: 'sk1',
            product1: [],
            product2: []
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            sks: 'sk2',
            product1: [],
            product2: []
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            sks: 'sk3',
            product1: [],
            product2: []
        }];
```

Here a product3 is directly added when I click on a button in HTML , however after the product9 the product10 appers in next block to product1 , which i later found out is becuase the products are being displayed in alphabetical order

My HTML

```
   </div>
    <!-- in this division the values are the ones to be shown -->

    <div class="row" id="{{x.id}}" ng-repeat="x in tableContent">

        <div class="cell" ng-click=openModal(x)> {{x.sks}} </div>

        <div class="cellD" ng-repeat="(key, value) in x" ng-if="key !== 'id' && key !=='sks' ">
            {{key}}    {{ value }}
            <div class=row ng-repeat=" prod in value">

                <div class=cell>{{prod}}

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class=row>
                <div class="cell" ng-click="modalBoxOpen(key,x.id)">+</div>
            </div></div>
```

also if the values like ProductA or productB are given they , despite being whatever order in the JSON are displayed in alphabetical order

Comment: i think you can try order by id. Is that okay with you?

Comment: can you show us the js where you added a new product object?

Comment: @CharlieNg the values are added to my json to every component

Comment: @NairAthul the ID order is fine , it only shows in alphabetical order when the values inside the JSON object are not alphabtical , for example if i give the SKS in the loop they will appear after product as S comes after P

Comment: I think you may create a jsfiddle for actually identify the issue :)

Comment: The issue is that  because product10 < product9, however I dont want the display to be alphabetical at all , the looping is automatically sorting my JSON

Comment: @Vibhor Can you make a fiddle and show us your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious. because **product10 < product9**.

if you wanna order your products based on this kind of sequence you must consider this. for example you can use *product09* instead of *product9* or handle it manually use compare function. or you can take another field using for order like **id**.

Comment: I asked a solution for the products shows in non alphabetical order , i cannot think of a way :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the orderBy:

```
<div class="row" id="{{x.id}}" ng-repeat="x in tableContent | orderBy: 'id'">
```

Comment: the problem is in the line    <div class="cellD" ng-repeat="(key, value) in x" ng-if="key !== 'id' && key !=='sks' ">     when the value with same key can have different products so , i cant sort it by key or ID either